# How to loop in JSX and use as component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i am trying to import every icon using 'react-icons' package. Its importing fine but when i am trying to use them as a component in my loop it wont display anything.

```
import * as fa from "react-icons/fa";

{Object.values(fa).forEach((value) => {
  <value/>
})}
```

I didn't wanted to copy the majority of the code as it has nothing to do, just keep in mind that i am using the object function in return.

Comment: Don't you mean to use `Object.values(fa).map`?

Comment: @JuanMendes arent they the same?

Comment: If they were the same, why would both exist? Map returns a value, but forEach just iterates, doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected, you're not returning anything, you're just iterating over an array of objects.

For such rendering manipulation just use `map`, and it's preferable to Capitalize the first letter of the component, and adding a key when iterating to help in the behind the scenes process :

```js
Object.values(fa).map((Value, idx)=>(<Value key={idx}/>))
```

Comment: make it `{Object.values(fa).map(Value=>(<Value/>))}`

Comment: @Areg Interesting that you accepted the answer that was incorrect until you pointed out its problem while there were at least three answers that were valid. keikai's is the most complete of all.

Comment: @JuanMendes they were slow compared to the one i chose. So it had to be justified somehow. I upped their reponses aswell

Answer (score 3):

Some notice points:

- Change `value` to `Value`: use Uppercase first letter for JSX element
- Change `forEach()` to `map()`: for loop in JSX with return
- Change `{}` to `()`: to give a return for each item
- Add a key (maybe not an index but add one)

```
{Object.values(fa).map((Value, idx) => (
  <Value key={idx} />
))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Custom JSX tags should start with capital letter
and also if you want to render them then use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` because it return an array.


code should be like that:

```
import * as fa from "react-icons/fa";

{Object.values(fa).map((Icon) => {
  <Icon />
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

forEach has no return value, hence nothing will rendered

```js
{Object.values(fa).map((value) => {
  <value/>
})}
```

Comment: would only work if parameter and component name are capitlized.But still thx, the other guy was faster than you

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```js
import * as fa from "react-icons/fa";

{Object.values(fa).map((value) => <value />)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a variable starting with a capital, and you need to use `map` sp that a new array is returned, `forEach` doesn't return anything

```
Object.values(fa).map((Value) => {
  <Value></Value>
})
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PIIwVgpgxgLgdANwIYBsCuEDOAKAZkgSjgFskAHbbANVQwIAIBeAPnoG8Aoe+gHhvQjMeAen4ZmHAL4EOsoA

Comment: Nothing says that he's using typescript.

Comment: @IlSaggioVecchino Typescript can be used to parse JSX. I didn't actually use any TypeScript features here, it's just a link that shows that it does compile to the correct JS. If you had done that to your answer, you'd see that yours doesn't work since you have lower case `value` :D Hoping you weren't the downvoter ;)

Comment: The main problem was that the code wasn't returning any item. But yes indeed, components should be capital first otherwise jsx will treat them as simple html tags. I corrected my answer.